# Query: Count id from table where parameter is counted NULL times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As a title I have a table named: campagne_cliente

```
CREATE TABLE `campagne_cliente` (
  `id_campagna_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cliente_id_campagna` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `impianto_id_campagna` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome_campagna_cliente` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where impianto_id_campagna is the id of the products contained in another table.

I need the query to count the parameter number (impianto_id_campagna)from the table campagne_cliente, when it is null.

vulgarly told how many times the parameter impianto_id_campagna was not put, for all id_campagna_cliente

Practice:

```
  `id_campagna_cliente` = 5
  `cliente_id_campagna` = 12
  `impianto_id_campagna` =
  `nome_campagna_cliente` = facoltative name
```

my try:

```
select count('impianto_id_campagna')
FROM campagne_cliente
HAVING COUNT(impianto_id_campagna) > 1
GROUP BY campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente;
```

Comment: Switch order, put GROUP BY before HAVING.

Comment: impianto_id_campagna is defined as NOT NULL. The count of nulls in the column is 0

Comment: this doesn't make a lot of sense. As Caius says, the columns are all NOT NULL. So none of them can ever be set to NULL. Even if you make the query correct, you'll never get any useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set impianto_id_campagna as default NULL or try

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM campagne_cliente
WHERE impianto_id_campagna = 0 /* If set as default null, use impianto_id_campagna IS NULL */
```

impianto_id_campagna is integer so the default value is 0 when you don't define it.